# Migrating UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper from SpringSecurity 3 to 4

Tags: spring-security

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-core-udsw

> UserDetailsServiceWrapper was deprecated in favor of using RoleHierarchyAuthoritiesMapper

Given the following snippet from applicationContext-security.xml file, what does the following need to be migrated to?:

```xml
    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
                    class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userLogic"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```